# C: Using fgets() to receive a char for some reason seems to set an unrelated integer variable to 0

Tags: c

I'm a begginer in C; I made this mainly to test using fgets() and stop using scanf(), but as I was messing around with this code something weird happened. I compiled and ran this program:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char c;

    printf("Input an integer: ");
    scanf("%i", &i);

    printf("Number received: %i\n", i);

    getchar(); // clear '\n' from input

    printf("Input a character: ");
    //scanf("%c", &c);
    fgets(&c, 2, stdin);

    printf("Integer: <%i>\n", i);
    printf("Char: <%c>\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
12
r
```

Output:

```
Input an integer: 12
Number received: 12
Input a character: r
Integer: <0>
Char: <r>
```

So, I am curious as to why 'i' is being set to 0. Commenting fgets() and uncommenting scanf() makes the program work as intended. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fgets(&c, 2, stdin);` : An invalid buffer size is specified. So `char c;` --> `char c[2];` then `fgets(c, 2, stdin);` or `fgets(&c[0], 2, stdin);` and `printf("Char: <%c>\n", *c);` or `printf("Char: <%c>\n", c[0]);`

Comment: The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>` for the functions: `printf()`, `scanf()`, `getchar()`, `fgets()`, `stdin`

Comment: when calling: `fgets()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  With the posted code, the returned value should be 1

Comment: regarding: `printf("Char: <%c>\n", c);`  after correcting the size of the 'c' variable,  then use: `printf("Char: <%c>\n", c[0]);  so it only tries to print the first char in the `c[]` array

Comment: regarding: `getchar(); // clear '\n' from input`  this is not guaranteed to work as expected.  suggest: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
fgets(&c, 2, stdin);
```

claims that `&c` is a pointer to a `char` within an array of `char`s, with at least one valid `char` immediately after `c`.  It is not, so your program has undefined behavior.

(So anything could happen, but it looks like what actually happened in your case is the read overflowed the `c` variable and also modified a byte of the `i` variable, which happened to be adjacent in memory.)

Answer (score 0):

the minimum size for a buffer that will be used with `fgets()` is 3 characters. And it doesn't hurt to make it significantly longer, for instance 1024 characters.

As it is, the `char 'c'` will ALWAYS be overrun, resulting in undefined behavior.  Remember, `fgets()` inputs right up to a newline (or 1 less than the length given as the second parameter.  And the function always appends a NUL byte  So, replace:

```
char c'
```

with

```
char c[1024];
```

then replace

```
fgets(&c, 2, stdin);
```

with

```
fgets( c, sizeof(c), stdin );
```

Notice no need for a '&' in the call to `fgets()` because the array 'c[]' will degrade to the address of the first byte of that array.